# Need help in clearing certain doubts in my swing app

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

Below is a simple swing app in which i was experimenting certain custom techniques.The code is as follows :-

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class ThemeComponents extends JFrame{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new    ThemeComponents();}});
  }

  public ThemeComponents()
  {
    super("HACK 1:Creating Image Themed Components ");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    CustomPanel p1=new CustomPanel();
    p1.add(new CustomLabel());
    add(p1);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
  }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel
{
  BufferedImage img;
  CustomPanel()
  {
    try
    {
      img=ImageIO.read(new File("src/background.jpg"));
    } catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println("Error in loading background image "+e);
    }
  }
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    g.drawImage(img,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);
  }
  public Dimension getPreferredSize()
  {
    return new Dimension(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight());
  }
}

class CustomLabel extends JLabel
{
  ImageIcon img;
  CustomLabel ()
  {
    img=new ImageIcon("src/tornado.gif");


    setSize(img.getIconWidth(),getHeight());
    setIcon((Icon) img);
    //setOpaque(false);
    //setIconTextGap(0);
    setLocation(10,10);
  }
}
```

Now I have following questions :-

1)When i set the layout to null `setLayout(null)` in my main class `ThemeComponents` then why the frame size shrinks to null with only title bar ?I expected it to take the size of `CustomPanel` as i have used `pack()` for the frame.(using layouts such as flowlayout , borderlayout however produces correct output)

2)Is using `getPreferredSize()` better for setting the size of component instead of `setPreferredSize()`.Actually i don't find any difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you use `null`-layout, preferred size will return (0,0) and hence you will only see the title bar. `pack()` validates your `JFrame` and then sets the size of the `JFrame` to the preferred size of the content pane (which is 0,0) and add the required space for the title bar, menus, etc...
2. Most likely you should avoid calling `setPreferredSize()` and rather override `getPreferredSize()`. Calling `setPreferredSize()` leaves the possibility to others to modify that value. In such situation it probably means that the preferred size is not an intrinsic part of your component and therefore you should not need to call `setPreferredSize()`. While overriding `getPreferredSize()` gives you full control and results in the preferred size being an intrinsic part of your component.
3. You should also call `super.paintComponent(g);` in your CustomPanel.
4. In your `CustomLabel`, it does not make any sense to call `setLocation` (the parent layout will change that anyway)
5. In your `CustomLabel`, this does not make any sense either: `setSize(img.getIconWidth(),getHeight());` since the parent layout will change those values anyway (and btw, `getHeight()` returns 0 in this case)

Answer (score 0):

setLayout() is used to set the layout of your window, for layouts [click here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit591-2004/Pages/layout-examples.html)
Content panes use BorderLayout by default, by setting your layout to null there just 
is no layout and all you see is the title bar.

getPreferred() is used to GET the preferred size you gave to a component, while the set 
is used to SET the preferred size :p

Comment: :Yup!! but even if there is no layout the panel should be there and it must give the frame its size